# SpringBoot war file - scanBasePackages not working for beans inside jar file

Tags: spring-boot

We have a SpringBoot application which is deployed as a war file. In the main ApplicationClass we have scanBasePackages with a path expression different from the package of the ApplicationClass.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= { "com.test.cmn" })
@EnableCaching
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
    }

    /**
     * @see org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer#onStartup(javax.servlet.ServletContext)
     * @param servletContext
     * @throws ServletException
     */
    @Override
    public void onStartup( ServletContext servletContext ) throws ServletException{
        //WebEnviromentConfiguration.setActiveProfile(servletContext);
        servletContext.setInitParameter( "spring.profiles.active", "dev" );
        super.onStartup( servletContext );
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure( SpringApplicationBuilder builder ){
        return builder.sources( Application.class );
    }
}
```

The base package scanning is working for the Beans that are there in the WEB-INF/classes folder. But the beans which are there in the jar file is not detected. But we are able to see those beans in the application class path (by loading the classes explicitly).

Is there something else that we need to do to auto detect those beans?

Comment: Have a look at this answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/28679612/8112217 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/39877504/8112217

Comment: But the second one tells about including in the main application as sub packages. But we have difficulty in doing that due to project structure. It’s scanning the packages which are not part of the jar and not sub package.