# How to add a Spring Boot Jar in another spring boot project and auto wire it

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I try to add spring boot project(A) to spring boot project(B) as dependency it's added but I can't auto wire
in project(A) I added below plugin and in project(B) I added project(A) as dependency in pom(B)

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build information</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>repackage</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/28679581/8283737

Comment: It means there is no `UploadedFilesRepo` generated by spring. Does you application or the spring boot jar you talk about has `UploadedFilesRepo`? and is it annotated with `@Repositories`?

Comment: its working fine many thanks

Comment: i have another question if i need to scan properties file of project(a) how i can do that

Comment: you can try using `@PropertySources`

Comment: i used it and it's working fine, thank you :)